# Odd Integers in Different Bases

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that an integer in an odd base is odd in base 10 if and only if it has an odd number of odd digits. For example, $223_{base5} = 50+10+3=63_{base10}$.

Intuitively, this makes perfect sense, but how can I go about showing it?

Comment: odd in base 10?

Comment: Yes, trying to show that an integer in an odd base with an odd number of odd digits is odd in base 10.

Comment: I think you mean the number itself is odd. Since a number being odd means it is not divisible by $2$. Which does not depend in the base it is written.

Answer (score 1):

We shall prove a number expressed in an odd base is odd if and only if it has an odd number of odd digits.

Indeed the number $a_na_{n-1}\dots a_1a_0$ in base $k$ represents the number $a_nk^n+a_{n-1}k^{n-1}\dots a_1k+a_0$

Since $k$ is odd we have :

$a_nk^n+a_{n-1}k^{n-1}\dots a_1k+a_0\equiv a_n+a_{n-1}+\dots a_{0} \bmod 2$

This is because $k^l\equiv1\bmod 2$ for all $l\in \mathbb N$ (A power of an odd number is odd)

So a number in an odd base $k$ is odd if and only if the sum of its digits is odd. This happens if and only if there is an odd number of odd digits.